# How to gauge the scalability of websockets in an application

Tags: websocket, scalability, amazon-elb, micronaut

I am struggling to find information on how to gauge the scalability of websockets. A scenario -

Let's say from client wants to establish socket connection from a browser, and the client application and service layer (Micronaut) both have two instances behind an elb - service layer will sit us-east region and can expect anyone from around the world can access the frontend app from browser and can expect an open connection for an avg of 2-5 min, no longer than 30 minutes.

Is there a ballpark number on how many concurrent websocket connections a couple servers can handle? Or if there are certain factors that I didn't mention that are vital to handling websocket connections in general?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which Micronaut runtime are you using?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown running on jre

Comment: " running on jre" - Right.  Are you using Jetty or a servlet container?

Comment: sorry, am using netty @JeffScottBrown

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to know the scalability of the implementation of WS in Micronaut and not WS in general. Of course, the scalability of WS is dependent on the specific implementation and WS itself. You probably already know this, but wanted to state it for the record. You may also want to be sure you increase your file descriptors for your server process to the max number (you may have to adjust your kernel to increase the FDs).

Btw, don't forget to handle retries and reconnects as you would for a low-level TCP connection